# Mockito: not throwing error in a test function

Tags: java, exception, mocking, mockito

I tried to test some functionalities by using `junit` and `mockito`.

But due to some reasons unknown to me, I cannot successfully test throwing of an exception.

This is my code:

**UserService:**

```
public class UserService {
   private final UserRepository userRepository;
   private final CheckSomething checkComething;

   public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, CheckSomething checkComething) {
       this.userRepository = userRepository;
       this.checkSomething = checkSomething;
   }

   public boolean isValidUser(String id, String something) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id);
        return isEnabledUser(user) && isValidSomething(user, something);
   }

   private boolean isEnabledUser(User user) {
        return user != null && user.isEnabled();
   }

   private boolean isValidSomething(User user, String something) {
       String checkedSomething = checkSomething.check(something);
       return checkedSomething.equals(user.getSomething());
   }
}
```

**CheckSomething:**

```
public interface CheckSomething{
    String check(String something);
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
public interface UserRepository {
    User findById(String id);
}
```

**User:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String something;
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

**This is the testing method:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    private CheckSomething checkSomething;

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testThrowingRandomException() {
        Mockito.when(checkSomething .check(Mockito.anyString())).thenThrow(new IllegalArgumentException());

        userService.isValidUser("1", "1");
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me why is the testing method not throwing any error?

Comment: Please add your complete test class, or at least how you mock `passwordEncoder` and how you create `userService`.

Comment: I added it, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user is missing. `isValidUser()` checks `isEnabledUser()` first which returns false because your repository does not return an user. So `isValidSomething()` is never executed and can't throw any exception.